# Correlation matrix in tensorflow with variable entries

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a k-by-k symmetric matrix in tensorflow where the diagonal is a constant 1 and the off-diagonal entries are variable.

i.e.:

```
k = 3
a = tf.Variable(1.0*tf.ones([k*(k-1)/2, 1]))
```

Then:

```
Rho =
[[1, a[0], a[1]],
[[a[0], 1, a[2]],
[[a[1], a[2], 1]]
```

Is there some straighforward tensorflow implementation to get me from `k` and `a` to `Rho`? Solving for a correlation matrix is common, so I suspect that a straighforward implementation of this should exist w/in tf.

Thanks!

**One proposal**

Following the logic above for `k=3`, it would be sufficient to get a strict-upper-triangular matrix `U` from `a` and then `Rho` would simply be:

```
U = tf.[strictly_upper_triangular](a)
Rho = tf.eye(k) + U + tf.transpose(U)
```

Is there such a function as `[strictly_upper_triangular]`?

Comment: How would `Rho` be formed from `a` for larger values of `k`?

Comment: It really makes no difference how 'Rho' should be formed, but it should be structured based on `k`. I gave one example, where the off-diagonals are filled first by row then by column, and the lower part is equivalent.

Comment: So there should probably be something to construct the upper-off-diagonal elements from `a`, call it `U`, then we can do `Rho = tf.eye(k) + U + tf.transpose(U)`

Comment: Is `k` fixed and known at graph construction time or is it a TensorFlow intermediate value? (that is, can I use `k` to build a NumPy matrix to use as constant in the graph?)

Comment: `k` is known at construction time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

k = 5
# Using a constant instead now for testing
#a = tf.Variable(1.0 * tf.ones([(k * (k - 1)) // 2, 1]))
a = 10 * tf.range((k * (k - 1)) // 2, dtype=tf.float32) + 10
# Make indices and mask
idx = np.zeros((k, k), dtype=int)
mask = np.zeros((k, k), dtype=bool)
triu_idx = np.triu_indices(k, 1)
idx[triu_idx] = np.arange((k * (k - 1)) // 2)
mask[triu_idx] = True
# Make upper triangular matrix
u = tf.where(mask, tf.gather(a, idx), tf.zeros((k, k), dtype=a.dtype))
# Final matrix
Rho = tf.eye(k, dtype=u.dtype) + u + tf.transpose(u)
print(sess.run(Rho))
```

Output:

```
[[   1.   10.   20.   30.   40.]
 [  10.    1.   50.   60.   70.]
 [  20.   50.    1.   80.   90.]
 [  30.   60.   80.    1.  100.]
 [  40.   70.   90.  100.    1.]]
```

The drawback is that the `k` must be known at graph construction time, since the indices and mask matrices are constructed with NumPy.

Comment: I offered an update but it seems to stil not work. What exactly is going on here? This only works when `k=3`

Comment: Basically, the size of `a` will be `k*(k-1)/2` when the size of the matrix is `[k, k]`

Comment: @AOK Right, fixed that now I think.

Comment: By the way, k*(k-1) is always divisible by 2, so no need for `//`

Comment: @AOK Yes you're right about that, it's just that in Python 3 `/` always returns a float so `np.arange` for example would return an array of floats (it doesn't really matter in this case because it is cast to integer but anyway).